# How to show image or text based on some condition

Tags: java, jasper-reports, alignment

I have *JR* report in which image and *Text Fields* are present in the *Title* band. I have taken image from database and fields from passed parameter.

Now I want that text field in center when image is null and if image is not null then text field is on right side of image.

Please suggest any answer.

Comment: Provide your efforts.

Comment: Now as a result i am getting blank space when image is not present in database & getting image when it is in database but i am unable to move text.

Answer (score 0):

Create two text fields and set the `Print When Expression`property for one text field to display on the condition that the image field is null and have the other to be hidden.

Comment: Thanks for answer But can i move(position) the text field according to the image appearance with this answer.

Comment: No, the fields will stay in fixed position. You can set a text field to 'float' but as far as I'm aware you can only float vertically and not horizontally.